# É adequado migrar recursos comuns a mais de um projeto para um pacote independente?

Tags: php, composer

Construi dois pacotes em PHP, cada um destes realizam funções bem distintas, porém, ambos implementam praticamente as mesmas interfaces e classes abstratas.

Por conta disso criei um terceiro pacote contendo somente as interfaces e classes abstratas utilizas, ou seja, este pacote contem o esqueleto básico compartilhado pelas outras duas bibliotecas. As interfaces ficam abaixo do do diretório Contratos, já os diretórios Auxiliares e Conectores possuem classes abstratas:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Já um dos pacotes possui a estrutura:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Porém, acho que está organização não parece muito satisfatória. Alguma ideia de como melhorar isso, ou até mesmo sugestões de organização?

Obs: O carregamento via autoload está sendo feito pelo composer

A ideia é separar em um pacote as classes abstratas, interfaces e traits padrões para 2 pacotes ou mais...

Comment: Acho que pode ser util sim, ainda mais se irá reutilizar em mais de um projeto. Eu mesmo fiz isso com um projeto que eu tinha, isso porque se tiver que fazer o update não afeta o resto do projeto.

Comment: Entendi. Então tudo indica ser uma boa estratégia. E na sua opinião, essa estrutura de arquivos poderia ser diferente? Algo nela me incomoda.

Comment: Sim, mas não identifiquei nada sugerindo local e nome de classes abstratas, interfaces etc

Comment: Compreendi. Bem, minha dúvida era, no pacote genérico eu tenho as interfaces e classes abstratas. Já nos pacotes principais, que implementam essas interfaces e classes abstratas eu tenho classes especializadas, mas com o mesmo nome. Por exemplo: PacoteGenerico\Bibliotecas\Cpu e no pacote principal PacotePrincipal\Bibliotecas\Cpu. A diferença é que nos pacotes principais são classes especializadas. É considerado inadequado ter o mesmo nome da interface para a classe?

Comment: Eu pessoalmente nunca dividiria por pastas pacoteprincipal\bibliotecas\Cpu, sempre faço `Vendor\Categoria\Cpu`, e tudo vai dentro da pasta vendor controlado pelo composer (seria legal estudar ele primeiro) e se uma classe repete o nome e ainda usa o mesmo namespace é porque já esta errado. Não é errado se o namespace for diferente.

Comment: Obrigado Guilherme, postei no github https://github.com/crphp/wmi que faz uso de outro pacote https://github.com/crphp/core. Obviamente terei que melhorar muita coisa, mas ao menos é um passo inicial.

Comment: eu não teria dividido em dois repositórios, bastaria criar uma pasta chamada `./src/Core/` e outra `./src/Wmi/`

Comment: É que terão outros 2 pacotes distintos que utilizarão o core. E eles não dependem do Wmi, logo, não queria obrigar o usuário a instalar o Wmi se por exemplo ele quiser só o Ssh

Comment: Neste caso faz todo sentido, fez muito bem. só um detalhe, notei que o Wmi depende do Core e já esta no composer.json, ficou ótimo assim.

Comment: Inclusive estou escrevendo uma biblioteca SSH que utiliza a classe abstrata Conector e todas as outras interfaces. Nos próximos dias já devo está publicando, essa abordagem está me poupando bastante tempo de desenvolvimento